# Converting Custom WinForms Controls to Equivalent Custom WPF Controls

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, custom-controls

Being fully aware I am some number of years (or possibly even a decade or more) late to the party, I've finally left my comfort zone in WinForms and begun exploring Windows Presentation Foundation, for various reasons that are not relevant to this conversation.

As both a practical and a learning exercise, I've begun converting two of our favorite and most commonly used WinForms Custom Controls (NOT User Controls) from WinForms to WPF :

the [gLabel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95399/gLabel-Custom-Label-with-Special-Effects-VB-NET) and the [GlassButton](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17695/Creating-a-Glass-Button-using-GDI).

To that end, I am hoping to find somewhere, SOMEWHERE, a guide similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751565(v=vs.100).aspx) microsoft guide for mapping WinForm Controls properties onto the WPF WindowsFormsHost Element.

Mind you, I have absolutely zero desire to use the WindowsFormsHost Element unless there is absolutely no alternative, for two reasons

- This is a learning exercise through which I want to familiarize myself with Windows Presentation Format
- This is a practical exercise by which we will be converting two of our favorite controls into something that is usable in a new format.

Realizing fully this is not the proper venue for this sort of question (and if someone would like to relocate this question to the proper venue (or to me indicate where that venue IS, so that I can do that myself) so that it receives the proper attention, that would be awesome), the question I have is : 
**Does there exist a chart that compares WinForms Control Structures and Properties (such as System.Drawing.Font) to WPF "Control Structures and Properties" (such as the System.Windows.Media.FontFamily, and etc that make up the WPF equivalent of the System.Drawing.Font).**

Comment: It's not as simple as "mapping properties", since WPF and XAML are designed and used in a completely different manner than winforms. For one, there is no such thing as "owner draw" in WPF, there's the concept of "lookless controls", which means that a control's functionality is completely decoupled from it's visual representation, and there's the concept of [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) which I recommend you begin reading about. Besides, the amount of code reuse possible when porting from winforms to WPF is almost zero.

Comment: Unfortunately as you guessed, your question is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this website. As far as I'm aware, there is no direct correlation between WinForms and WPF. The best that I could find is the [Windows Forms Controls and Equivalent WPF Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN which may, or may not be of any help to you. Apart from that, it really is just a case of trial and error, but I'd certainly advise learning how to use WPF properly *before* attempting to convert your controls.

Comment: I don't think it is even worth to compare WF and WPF controls because they are not related. You need to start thinking in WPF terms like WF was never there. Public libraries these days full of books on WPF - pick one

Comment: Well, at the risk of sounding incredibly stupid, I've worked with JavaFX to a certain extent, as well as Swing, and I drew some pretty immediate parallels between FXML and XAML... FXML styles with CSS, XAML styles with resource libraries, both XAML and FXML seem to do a lot to divide interface from the actual application, and such. Anyway, before this gets closed, just want to say thanks for the advice.